# alignment of buttons in tkinter module

Tags: python, button, layout, tkinter

i am making a tkinter module Based GUI appplication
i want to align the button in the form of 2x2 layout but it doesnt align the button
instead it aligns the button in a line

i want to align Issue,Return,Status,Defaulters only in form of 2x2 layout.
the credits button should be at the bottom right

coding:

```
from tkinter import *
a = Tk()    # a is the window variable
a.title('Doodle Engine powered Library management')
a.geometry('580x300')
Label(text = "Library ManageMent", bg = "grey", width = "55", height = "1", font = ("Calibri", 13)).pack(side = "top")
bt_issue = Button(a,text = 'Issue',width = 9, height = 1, )
bt_issue.pack(padx=25, pady=10, side=LEFT)      #sets button issue
bt_return = Button(a,text = 'Return',width = 9, height = 1, )
bt_return.pack(padx=25, pady=20, side=LEFT)     #sets button return 
bt_status = Button(a,text = 'Status',width = 9, height = 1, )
bt_status.pack(padx=25, pady=20, side=LEFT)     #sets button status 
bt_default = Button(a,text = 'Defaulters',width = 9, height = 1, )
bt_default.pack(padx=25, pady=20, side=LEFT)    #sets button defaulter 
bt_credits = Button(a,text = 'Credits',width = 9, height = 1, )
bt_credits.pack()    #sets button credit 
a.mainloop()     #sets the GUI running
```

I am using python 3.7.0 on win 10 through anaconda distribution

Comment: Use a `Frame` with [The Tkinter Grid Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm)

Comment: Have you tried using `grid`? It's the natural choice when arranging widgets in a grid.

Comment: i saw the net but it was not usefull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from tkinter import *
a = Tk()    # a is the window variable
a.title('Doodle Engine powered Library management')
a.geometry('580x300')
Label(text = "Library ManageMent", bg = "grey", width = "55", height = "1", font = ("Calibri", 13)).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
bt_issue = Button(a,text = 'Issue',width = 9, height = 1, )
bt_issue.grid(padx=25, pady=10, row=1, column=0)      #sets button issue
bt_return = Button(a,text = 'Return',width = 9, height = 1, )
bt_return.grid(padx=25, pady=20, row=1, column=1)     #sets button return
bt_status = Button(a,text = 'Status',width = 9, height = 1, )
bt_status.grid(padx=25, pady=20, row=2, column=0)     #sets button status
bt_default = Button(a,text = 'Defaulters',width = 9, height = 1, )
bt_default.grid(padx=25, pady=20, row=2, column=1)    #sets button defaulter
bt_credits = Button(a,text = 'Credits',width = 9, height = 1, )
bt_credits.grid(row=3, column=1)    #sets button credit
a.mainloop()     #sets the GUI running
```

Comment: congrats Partho63  this gave the desired output